# error TS2307: Cannot find module '.shaders/vertex.glsl' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, glsl, tsconfig

Currently I'm getting the below error from trying to import some files as strings into my `main.ts`.

```
main.ts:2:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './shaders/vertex.glsl' or its corresponding type declarations.
main.ts:3:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './shaders/fragment.glsl' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

main.ts:

```
// shader
import vsource from ".shaders/vertex.glsl";
import fsource from ".shaders/fragment.glsl";
```

typings/glsl.d.ts:

```
declare module "*.glsl" {
    const value: string;
    export default value;
}
```

tsconfig:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

        /* Basic Options */
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es2019",
            "dom"
        ] ,
        "allowJs": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "strictBindCallApply": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,

        "noUnusedLocals": false,      
        "noUnusedParameters": false,  
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true ,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./typings"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true 
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": ["main.ts"]
}
```

my folder structure:

[image: my folder structure]

Does anyone know why this error is occurring and how I can fix it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `./shaders/vertex.glsl`? You don't have directory named `.shaders` anywhere in provided structure.

Comment: Indeed. Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `"include": ["main.ts"]` and now it works. I was told that adding the `main.ts` makes the `main.ts` the only file that gets compiled.